# Unable to refresh AD access_token through Easy Auth (403)

Tags: azure, oauth, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I cannot seem to figure out where I went wrong in setting up an Azure Easy Auth for an app service:

I have a single app service that uses Azure Easy Auth (with Azure AD as the provider) & a token store turned on. When I visit my application, I am prompted to login. Once logged in, I can visit `/.auth/me` and I can see both an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. After 60mins or so, the `access_token` expires. The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-oauth-tokens#refresh-auth-tokens) explain all I have to do is call `/.auth/refresh` to generate a new `access_token`. This does not work for me - I am getting a 403 Access Denied back.

My scope does include `offline_access` and I am retrieving a `refresh_token` in `/.auth/me` but the refresh will just not work. It has also not been revoked since logging in. Annoyingly, I cant find any application logs to tell me why this is failing (I have turned everything on but I am running a Node js app which uses PM2 in the background and doesnt seem to log anything from the Easy Auth module?).

To make things stranger, I can manually retrieve a new token by using the OAuth endpoint (POSTing to https://login.microsoftonline.com/) so I don't believe there is any issue with any of the tokens in the token store.

What could be causing this? How can I debug it?

Edit: From doing some testing, it looks like this is caused by an extra scope in my login params. My application requires this scope, but removing it seems to fix the issue. I assume it is failing to refresh the token because the other scope does not support it? What updates do I need to do to allow token refreshing on this custom scope?

```
"loginParameters": ["scope=openid profile email offline_access api://xxx-xxx-xxx/user_impersonation"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, I had to add the API scope of the app registration to the "Authorized client applications" for the app registration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When your provider's access token expires and still if you want to use that token you need to do ***reauthenticate*** the user before you can use that token again. For that purpose you will want to give the necessary permissions,i.e ***`READ/WRITE`*** to the azure resource manager provider named microsoft.web in your subscription to the resources in the concerned resource group.

You can do so by following the below steps:

- Go to Microsoft: In https://resources.azure.com
  At the top of the page, select Read/Write.
- In the left browser, navigate to ***subscriptions > <subscription_name > resourceGroups > <resource_group_name> > providers > Microsoft.Web > sites > <app_name> > config > authsettingsV2.***
- Click Edit.
- Modify the following property.

  ```
   "azureActiveDirectory": {
     "login": {
       "loginParameters": ["scope=openid profile email offline_access"]
     }
   }
  }
  ```
- Click Put.

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***: [***Work with OAuth tokens in Azure App Service authentication***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-oauth-tokens#refresh-auth-tokens)