# Access refresh token in Azure easy auth application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I have an azure application to which I can login with my AD account. The app registration used for the authentication has the `User.Read` permission and I just added the `Offline_access`. I previously would not see the refresh token when navigating to `/.auth/me` and would get `Permission denied` when navigating to `/.auth/refresh`. I thought adding `Offline_access` api permission to the app registration would fix it, however I am still getting the issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: found a similar question some of the answers might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/71010008/6696446